# How to retrieve VisualChild from ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF application in .NET 3.5 SP1 which is using `TabControl`.
In that we have `TabItems`, which in turn have their `Styles` to determine currently displayed items.
Let's say we have a `TabItem` named *Books*, now *Books* will have three stages of display:
1. Loading results,
2. Displaying results,
3. Displaying no results - i.e. nothing found.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Books"/>
    <TabItem Header="DVD's"/>
    ...
</TavControl>
```

Now I have 5 `TabItems` which let's say represent "DVD's", "Blu-Rays", "CD's", "Books" and "Comics".

```
<TabItem Header="Books">
    <Control>
        <Control.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Control">
               <Setter Property="Template">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                           <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"/>
                       </ControlTemplate>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- Assign different Visuals depending on the current state of the app, i.e. Loading, No results, results found
                <DataTrigger .../>
            </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Control.Resources>
    </Control>
</TabItem>
```

Underneath the `TabItem` I have a `TextBlock` to display number of currently found results:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Displaying {0} records for your Shop ({1})" Converter="{StaticResource tstMVC}">
            <Binding ElementName="Tc" Path="SelectedValue"/>
            <Binding Path="ShopId" FallbackValue="Liverpool"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Converter is there for me to check what values are passed in the `MultiBinding`.
**ISSUE:**
When **user** selects a tab item I would like to display **current number** of the items displayed but I can't locate the `ListView` in the `Control`, as that's the Current Content of the `TabItem`.
I have tried TabControl.SelectedItem, SelectedValue and still can't find Current ItemsSource.Count.
Thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE:**
I have tried both of the solutions big thanks to @Sheridan and @pushpraj!
Unfortunately I haven't used either of them, instead I used ListView inside of the `TabItem` and then accessed it with this code:

```
<TabControl Name="Tc">
    <TabItem><ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"/></TabItem>
    ...
</TabControl>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Tc, Path=SelectedItem.Content.Items.Count}"/>
```

This way Content of my TextBlock changes every time user selects different Tab.
**P.S.** Nevertheless I wouldn't have done it without evaluation of both answers.

Comment: I would suggest to go data binding way. secondly to get number of items you may use `Items.Count` on TabControl. ItemsSource.Count only works when there is a Count property on the items source, eg IEnumarable do not have any.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but when I use `TabControl.Items.Count` I get number of TabItems, not number of the results returned from DB.

Comment: do you want the number of Books? perhaps binding to `{Binding Books.Count}` may help you get the desired.

Comment: my question is about Currently selected Tab, so yes current number of books, so at first user looks at books but when user changes to Comics it needs to display current number of comics and not books. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Indeed that make sense, but in that case you need to restructure your code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, we generally work with data elements rather than UI elements. By that, I mean that it is customary to data bind data elements from our code behind or view models to the UI elements in the views, `UserControl`s and `Window`s.

Therefore, if you have a data collection property named `Books` in your code behind or view model, then you can simply refer to that collection to find out how many items are in it, rather than trying to find it via the UI controls:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" />
```

You could even expose the count of items as a separate property and data bind to it directly:

```
public ObservableCollection<Book> Books
{
    get { return books; }
    set 
    { 
        books = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Books"); 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("BookCount");
    }
}

public int BookCount
{
    get { return Books.Count; }
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

In response to your latest comment, you can find out how to access UI elements from within a `ControlTemplate` from the [How to: Find ControlTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. In short though, you need to access the element that has the `ControlTemplate` applied (the relevant `TabItem` in your case) and then you can use the [`FrameworkTemplate.FindName` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the internally declared elements. Take this example from the linked page:

```
// Finding the grid that is generated by the ControlTemplate of the Button
Grid gridInTemplate = (Grid)myButton1.Template.FindName("grid", myButton1);

// Do something to the ControlTemplate-generated grid
MessageBox.Show("The actual width of the grid in the ControlTemplate: "
    + gridInTemplate.GetValue(Grid.ActualWidthProperty).ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks, BTW: I use MVVM Light in my app, I should've specified that first.

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference here.

Answer (score 1):

if you have separate collection classes for all you entities you may use the following approach

define data templates for your collection classes

eg

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:BookCollection}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

xaml

```
<TabControl x:Name="Tc">
    <TabItem Header="Books"
             Content="{Binding Books}" />
    <TabItem Header="DVD's"
             Content="{Binding DVDs}" />
</TabControl>
```

or if you do not have separate collections then use DataTemplate as follows

```
<TabControl  x:Name="Tc">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabItem Header="Books"
             Content="{Binding Books}" />
    <TabItem Header="DVD's"
             Content="{Binding DVDs}" />
</TabControl>
```

then the binding to get the selected tab's items count will be

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Content.Count, ElementName=Tc}" />
```

Comment: Nice one, I will now evaluate both answers and choose the one that did the best, in my opinion, job.

Comment: Great find @XAMlMAX! a ListView or any ItemsControl would also allow you to count number of binded items using Items property.last but not the least, happy coding :)